# How to bypass GNOME Terminal when sending keyboard input?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, escape-characters

When running an interactive shell application, how can I send it a key (or key combination) which would normally be intercepted by GNOME Terminal? In this particular instance it's the <kbd>F10</kbd> key which is intercepted.

Bonus points for a general-purpose solution which would work for things like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (might be useful for a shell script to configure shortcut commands) or in other terminals as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try disable the gnome shortcuts in *Edit -> Keyboard shortcuts*, so the window won't eat up the function keys.

There seems to be a [known gnome-terminal bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/96676) relating to this.

Alternatively if this doesn't work, you will have to use another terminal that explicitly sends function keys as control codes to the terminal. [rxvt](http://www.rxvt.org/) is one I can recommend, or xterm.