# How to send Alt+1 to CLI when multiple tabs are open in gnome-terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, ranger, tabs

Both [`ranger`](https://ranger.github.io/) and the gnome-terminal use `Alt + 1`, `Alt + 2` etc to switch to the corresponding tab. So if a gnome-terminal window only has one tab and `ranger` is open, then pressing `Alt + 2` will go the second tab in `ranger`, but as soon as a second tab in the gnome-terminal window is open, `ranger` will no longer receive this command, it will always be captured by the gnome-terminal window.

Now this issue could easily be resolved by changing one or the other keybindings, but I'd like to avoid that.

Is there an alternative way to send the `Alt + 1`, `Alt + 2` etc commands to `ranger` even if we have multiple tabs in our gnome-terminal while using the default keybindings in both programs?

EDIT: I believe there was a similar issue in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32552/how-to-bypass-gnome-terminal-when-sending-keyboard-input), but maybe something has changed over the past 10 years.

Comment: If the terminal app uses some keyboard bindings it won't send it further down, period. Disable Alt + N bindings in the app and live happily ever after.

Comment: I'm asking because I can very well imagine this is not the case, for instance if there is only one tab the terminal *does* in fact send it further down. I know there are alternatives but I'm wondering specifically if there is a way to send these keys anyway.

Comment: When you have only one tab, Alt+number is not consumed by the xterminal, that's why you see this behaviour. Change/disable those xterminal shortcuts.

Comment: Press `Esc` followed by `1`.

Comment: @egmont Please consider adding that as an answer!

Comment: Turns you with`Esc,1` doesn't do the same thing in the situation described above. For anyone with the similar problem of gnome-terminal tabs and ranger: You can also use `gn` to create new tabs, and use `gt, gT` or `shift+Tab` to switch between them.